# Setting session timeout in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need help on the timeout configuration on the rails 6. I tried to configure the /config/initializers/devise.rb, but it's not working, any assist will be appreciated.

Step 1: 
Go to /config/initializers/devise.rb  configure:

```
config.timeout_in = 1.minutes
```

Step 2:
Go to /app/models/user.rb  Set :timeoutable in the user model.

```
 class User < ActiveRecord
    devise :timeoutable
end
```

Step 3: 
Systemctl restart nginx
Success!

System informations:

---

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.5.7p206 (2019-10-01 revision 67816) [x86_64-linux]

rails -v
Rails 6.0.0

Running on the CentOS 7.
```

Reference: 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set `:timeoutable` in User model? For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :timeoutable
end
```

and with this setting set this value `config.timeout_in = 1.minutes` in `/config/initializers/devise.rb` as before.

Devise docs:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-timeout_in-value-dynamically#this-feature-was-added-in-version-152-and-is-not-available-in-older-versions-of-devise

Comment: It should be kept in mind that `:timeoutable` and `:rememberable` can not come together, to make `:timeoutable` work separately write in User model `devise :timeoutable` other than `devise :database_authenticatable, ..` as mentioned above.